# Формула ВПР в Excel ищет неверное значение

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть excel файл с двумя листами. Во второй лист подтягиваются данные с помощью ВПР, однако подставляются неверные значения. В построителе функции результат верный, а в ячейке на листе значение другое. Прикепляю скрины:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем в поле Таблица вы используете формулу ЕСЛИ? Попробуйте сделать ВПР ссылаясь на таблицу без дополнительных вычислений.

Comment: @N1kolasLee без если все работает нормально, но такая проверка необходима

Comment: добавь в вопрос формулу и примеры данных

Comment: Конструкция формулы неправильная. Функция ЕСЛИ формирует массив, который никак не обрабатывается. При этом ВПР будет работать только в ячейках тех строк, для которых выполняется условие. Если нужно более подробное объяснение, покажите живой пример в файле... или просто примите, как аксиому - такая формула корректно работать не будет.